# No module named 'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ViewBox.axisCtrlTemplate_pyqt5' while executing exe

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

`No module named 'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ViewBox.axisCtrlTemplate_pyqt5'`

Facing with this error after creating exe file using pyinstaller.

- python -version: 3.8
- pyqtgraph -version: 0.12.3
- pyinstaller -version: 4.2

Comment: I solved this error by importing not founded module file into my python code.

`from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ViewBox.axisCtrlTemplate_pyqt5 import *`
`from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotItem.plotConfigTemplate_pyqt5 import *`
`from pyqtgraph.imageview.ImageViewTemplate_pyqt5 import *`
`from pyqtgraph.console.template_pyqt5 import *`

The problem is that, although .exe file run correctly, but part of program which contains plots does not display any plots.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you can post your comment as answer.

Comment: Actually I had solved that error. But as I mentioned, after running `.exe` I faced with another issue. So that is not the exact soloution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even with new versions of pyinstaller. Following [this](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/2179), I solved it by using an older version of pyinstaller (`pip install pyinstaller==4.8`).

Comment: I get "No module named 'pyqtgraph.examples'; 'pyqtgraph' is not a package"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the missing modules into `hiddenimports` of the `spec` file:

```py
a = Analysis(...,  # other parameters
             hiddenimports=[
                'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ViewBox.axisCtrlTemplate_pyside6',
                'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotItem.plotConfigTemplate_pyside6',
                'pyqtgraph.imageview.ImageViewTemplate_pyside6',
             ])
```

And it's not only `PyInstaller`'s fault. They have not prepared the hooks for the recent `pyqtgraph` update. The downgrade of `pyqtgraph` should help, but I haven't tried.